# tel URI scheme and my app

Tags: iphone

If i apply tel scheme in view 2.
After the call ends the app terminates.
Suppose my first view is login screen .
So wen the user logins he gets its state saved.

How can it be done ?
Help me Friends..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save session information to file (e.g. in *applicationWillTerminate* method). Then on launch you check it and if this session info is still valid - proceed to screen 2 directly.

Check "Saving State Information" and "Commonly Used Directories" in App Programming Guide.